# Notation of an Action Functional in Mathematics and Physics

Tags: notation, mathematical-physics

Considering the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_(physics)#cite_note-handfinch-3) on the meaning of *action* in Physics and for example also the first chapter of the book *Quantum Mechanics for Mathematicians* by *Leon A. Takhtajan*, one encounters the letter $S$ or $\mathcal{S}$ for action functionals. **Are there specific reasons for this?** I mean, in pure mathematics one often uses the letter $A$ or its caligraphic version $\mathcal{A}$, which is the first letter of "action". For example, this notation is used in the book *Critical Point Theory for Lagrangian Systems* by *Marco Mazzucchelli*.

Comment: [This Wikipedia entry may be relevant.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maupertuis%27s_principle#History)  In particular, it implies that the action was originally understood as a **s**tationary point.  I don't know if this is *actually* relevant, however. :\